# Get a number out of a string without spaces

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I grep this string from a SVG file:

`<g transform="translate(0.000000,980.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"`

and I want to get the number `980` within a bash script variable. My problem is that I don't manage to pipe the right expression to get only that number `980` out of the string. I need to add that, of course, the number `980` can be any number from any length (for example, `5967` or `98`...).

Could you offer me a solution? I'm stuck there...

Comment: "My problem is that I don't manage to pipe the right expression..." What did you try, and what happened?

Comment: I have tried different regexp expressions with sed, but I might have made them wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your SVG input file is `input.svg`. You should try:

```
cat input.svg | grep translate | sed 's/^.*translate(.*,\(.*\)\..*) scale.*$/\1/'
```

Comment: Works perfectly - Thanks a lot, DejanLekic. My regexp was wrong, it seems.

Comment: This can be reduced to `sed -n '/translate/s/^.*translate(.*,\(.*\)\..*) scale.*$/\1/p' INPUT_FILE` preventing use of **cat** and **grep** and printing only those lines that are affected with the change

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you can use awk.

```
grep whatever | awk -F"," '{print $2}' | awk -F"." '{print $1}'
```

Comment: `awk`'s `$n` variables are 1-based, `$0` is the whole line. You need to add 1 to both `print $n` statements.

Answer (score 0):

No need for more than one simple command:

```
awk -F"[,.]" '/your_search_string/{print $3}'
```

HTH Chris

Comment: What about adding `)` to the field delimiters?  What about possible false matches?

Answer (score 0):

just bash, I assume you want the 2nd parameter to "translate()"

```
$ line='<g transform="translate(0.000000,980.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"'
$ num=${line#*translate*,}; echo $num
980.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
$ num=${num%%.*}; echo $num
980
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/^<g transform/!d;s/[^,]*,//;s/[^0-9].*//
```

Answer (score 0):

The below awk command should work for you.

```
awk -v FS="[ =(,)]" '{print $5}' "Yourfilename" | awk -v FS="[.]" '{print $1}'
```